# Internet Explorer 11 won't read "getElementById" for XML and returns null

Tags: javascript, xml, httprequest, selectors-api

I wrote a webpage (with HTML, CSS, and javascript) which loads information from an XML file to "fill in the blanks" in the  elements on the page. Everything works perfectly unless I load the page in Internet Explorer (I'm using IE 11.0).

I've had a few problems and worked around a couple of them, but new problems keep popping up, so I think I just don't understand how IE deals with XML.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Unable to get property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined or null reference
```

when I use the code:

```
selectedBookNodeList = bookDataDocument.getElementById(bookId);
```

In the IE debugger it shows "selectedBookNodeList" as NULL, but the bookDataDocument is NOT null. Again, this works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox (here's a link: http://www.pattmayne.com/stories2/).

Why is it NULL in IE11, but it works fine in the other browsers??

Here is all the code:

```
    var bookPage;

    var bookDataDocument;
    var XMLConnection;



    var bookDataRootNode;
    var selectedBookNode;

    var bookDescription;
    var bookDescription2;
    var bookDescription3;
    var bookImage;
    var bookTitle;
    var paperbackLink;
    var ebookLink;



function setupXML()
{

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  XMLConnection=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
    else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  XMLConnection=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

    XMLConnection.open("GET", "novels/book_data.xml", false);
    XMLConnection.send(null);
    bookDataDocument = XMLConnection.responseXML;
}

    function setBook(bookId)
    {
        selectedBookNodeList = bookDataDocument.getElementById(bookId);

        bookTitle = selectedBookNodeList.querySelectorAll("title").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        bookDescription = selectedBookNodeList.querySelectorAll("description").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        bookDescription2 = selectedBookNodeList.querySelectorAll("description2").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        bookDescription3 = selectedBookNodeList.querySelectorAll("description3").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        ebookLink = selectedBookNodeList.querySelectorAll("ebookLink").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        paperbackLink = selectedBookNodeList.querySelectorAll("paperbackLink").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        bookImage = selectedBookNodeList.querySelectorAll("coverImage").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;


        bookPage = document.getElementById("storiesWindow").contentWindow.document;

        bookPage.getElementById("bookTitle").innerHTML = bookTitle;
        bookPage.getElementById("description").innerHTML = bookDescription;
        bookPage.getElementById("description2").innerHTML = bookDescription2;
        bookPage.getElementById("description3").innerHTML = bookDescription3;
        bookPage.getElementById("buyEbookLink").href = ebookLink;
        bookPage.getElementById("buyPaperbackLink").href = paperbackLink;
        bookPage.getElementById("coverImage").src=bookImage;

    }
```

I'd really love a solution, but I'd love even more to understand the dynamics that I'm obviously not understanding. I want to use XML for other stuff in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by skipping the "getElementById" statement altogether. Instead I queried for "book" and then used "getAttribute('id')" and wrote a function with a loop to compare the ids to the bookId that was sent to the original function.

Here's the fixed, working code:

```
    function setBook(bookId)
    {
        listOfBooks = bookDataDocument.querySelectorAll("book");

        selectedBook = listOfBooks.item(2);

        getSelectedBook(bookId);

        bookTitle = selectedBook.querySelectorAll("title").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        bookDescription = selectedBook.querySelectorAll("description").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        bookDescription2 = selectedBook.querySelectorAll("description2").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        bookDescription3 = selectedBook.querySelectorAll("description3").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        ebookLink = selectedBook.querySelectorAll("ebookLink").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        paperbackLink = selectedBook.querySelectorAll("paperbackLink").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        bookImage = selectedBook.querySelectorAll("coverImage").item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;


        bookPage = document.getElementById("storiesWindow").contentWindow.document;

        bookPage.getElementById("bookTitle").innerHTML = bookTitle;
        bookPage.getElementById("description").innerHTML = bookDescription;
        bookPage.getElementById("description2").innerHTML = bookDescription2;
        bookPage.getElementById("description3").innerHTML = bookDescription3;
        bookPage.getElementById("buyEbookLink").href = ebookLink;
        bookPage.getElementById("buyPaperbackLink").href = paperbackLink;
        bookPage.getElementById("coverImage").src=bookImage;

    }

    function getSelectedBook(bookId)
    {
            for (var i=0; i<listOfBooks.length; i++)
        {
            bookString = listOfBooks.item(i).getAttribute("id");

            if (bookString == bookId)
            selectedBook = listOfBooks.item(i);
        }

    }

    function setupXML()
    {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      XMLConnection=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      XMLConnection=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

        XMLConnection.open("GET", "novels/book_data.xml", false);
        XMLConnection.send(null);
        bookDataDocument = XMLConnection.responseXML;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know this is an old one but I came across the same issue yesterday with a client. The issue I found in this case was that the client had IE11 and Flash 11 but my PC had IE11 and Flash 14; I updated his flash and everything worked, sop looks like as Flash 11 was pre-IE11, there is some support issue within the DOM for the flash object.

Hope this helps someone else too :-)

Regards

Liam